# Order and Distinct ON conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql

assuming I have a table with 3 columns - letters and numbers and asci like so

```
  1 a !
  1 a ?
  2 a ^
  3 b *
  5 a $
  7 a &
```

I want to create a query so that it would first order it by the letter, and then by the number distinctly

so the result would be (distinct number, ordered by letter, then by id, then by asci. In this case `! < ?`)

```
1 a !
2 a ^
5 a $
7 a &
3 b *


select distinct on(number),letter, ascii
from table
order by letter, number, ascii
```

so this wouldn't make a distinct on number. But PG requires that the column in distinct would appear the same in the order by.

How can this be done?

Comment: Add 1 c and some other combinations to your sample data. Then show us the expected result!

Comment: But how do you chose ! instead of ? of the two number 1 rows? Do GROUP BY instead.

Comment: Why don't you simply change the order of columns in your select list? People usually expect data sorted from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `ORDER` *anything* ... "distinctly."

`ORDER BY` is obligated to sort every record that is presented to it.  So, if you want the values in the returned dataset to be `DISTINCT`, you merely specify that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, letter
  FROM table
  ORDER BY letter, number
```

You can include the `ORDER BY` clause, or not. The set of rows returned, **whether sorted or not**, will be `DISTINCT`.

Comment: i updated the question. This is true If the rows were the same. What if I want to distinct on number and the rows are not the same?

Comment: You can't have "distinct on number alone."  However, if you think about it, "either the result set is distinct, or it isn't."  Each row of the result-set is an *n-tuple* composed of the values of **all** the columns that you have requested.  The tuple `(a, 3)` is not the same as `(b,3)` because the entire set of all values, taken *together*, is what matters.  *That* result-set will be `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution based on first finding the first letter for a given number, then finding the first punctation for that letter.   For a serious sized table, you'd need to add a number,letter index as a minumum.

```
select t.number,t.letter,min(t.ascii) from 
(select number, min(letter) as first_letter from t group by number) x
inner join t on x.number = t.number and x.first_letter = t.letter
group by t.number, t.letter
order by 2,1;
```

Fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7617f/1

Alternatively you can do it using window functions.

```
select t.number,
min(t.letter),
first_value(min(t.ascii)) over (partition by t.number, min(t.letter)) from t
group by t.number
order by 2,1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3b3d/1